# Combining location from Nominatim with Overpass API query using Python

Tags: python, overpass-api, geolocation, nominatim

I try to get the geocodes coordinates from the location(nominatim) into the Overpass query.

Is there an easy way to do this?

```py
import json
import requests
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="your_app_name")
location = geolocator.geocode("Hufnerstraße 1, Hamburg")

lat = location.latitude
lng = location.longitude

print(lat, lng)

overpass_url = "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter"

overpass_query = """
[out:json];
(node["shop"](around:500,53.59057989074252,10.05931163368573);
        );out;
"""

response = requests.get(overpass_url, params={'data': overpass_query})
data = response.json()

print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the `overpass_query` is just a string, you can use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
overpass_query = f"""
[out:json];
(node["shop"](around:500,{lat},{lng});
        );out;
"""
```